# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Party"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

I am getting two errors with my project when I try to get by user id.

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Party"
    at model.Query.exec (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4927:21)
    at Query.findOne (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2628:8)
    at Function.findOne (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2379:13)
    at /home/emi/ffpf/routes/partyRouter.js:19:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at param (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"user"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'user',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/bson/lib/error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:67:23)
      at castObjectId (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:246:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1201:12)
      at SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1648:15)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1636:15)
      at SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1612:20)
      at cast (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:342:32)
      at Query.cast (/home/emi/ffpf/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5357:12),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

I pulled the ObjectId of the user in MongoDBCompass and it is
user: ObjectId('645d605091c8e45baaa4be4e')

The _id of the party itself is ObjectId('645d607391c8e45baaa4be51')

These seem to be good, right?

partyRouter.js

```
const express = require("express")
const partyRouter = express.Router()
const Party = require('../models/parties.js')

// Get parties by user id
partyRouter.get("/user", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.auth._id, "id")
  Party.find({ user: req.auth._id }, (err, parties) => {
    if(err){
      res.status(500)
      return next(err)
    }
    console.log(parties, "parties")
    return res.status(200).send(parties)
  })
})
```

parties.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const partySchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    eventStartTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    rolesNeeded: {
        type: Array,
        default: "any"
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Party", partySchema)
```

server.js

```
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authRouter.js'))
app.use('/api', expressjwt({ secret: process.env.SECRET, algorithms: ['HS256']})) // req.user
app.use('/api/parties', require('./routes/partyRouter.js'))
```

Any help about this would be great since I am completely new this and I think I got it mostly set up correctly and I am sure that I am missing something simple somewhere since this is the only part of my backend that isn't working in Postman. Thank you for trying to help me with my headache!

I have tried completely removing the ObjectId from the Party router but for some reason I keep getting the same error. I have also restarted my server, dropping the collection completely, and several other things.

EDIT:
The line 19 portion of the code referenced in partyRouter is as follows:

```
partyRouter.get("/:partyId", (req, res, next) => {
  Party.findOne({ _id: req.params.partyId },
    (err, foundParty) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500)
        return next(err)
      }
      return res.status(200).send(foundParty)
    }
  )

  }
)
```

It is worth noting that my find party by id works fine, however, finding them by user id does not work so I am unsure as to why that part of the code is being referenced.

Comment: That error seems to indicate the value `"user"` is begin passed somewhere.  Which line is called out in the error?

Comment: @Joe Thank you for the reply! I edited the question just now with the updated whole error. Sorry for accidentally leaving that part out!

Comment: I have resolved the issue but I am still looking for answers... For some odd reason, changing the endpoint for the find parties by user id to /api/parties/find/user works but if I change it back to /api/parties/user it will not work at all. I am wondering if this is an issue with Postman and its cache, or is there something that I can learn from so I can prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: That looks like it selects the wrong router, that `/:partId` route will catch any single-depth uri at that point, so it should be listed last in the file so the others are evaluated first.